# Pass More that one database record from child window to parent window dynamically

Tags: javascript, window, parent

How to add multiple record from child window to the parent window.?
Means when we select multiple records from child window pass that records to parent window and also update parent window without page refresh....

http://demo.vtiger.com/index.php?module=Invoice&action=EditView&return_action=DetailView&parenttab=Sales

use that link and add invoice from there...then goto add products one window will popup i want same functionality but dont have idea where to start

Comment: Do you have a way to pass a *single* database record to the parent window?

Comment: please add more info and a code snipet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create jquery function in parent window with some html dom in which response from child window can be placed on.

Now in child window code data for listing and create function and call parent window function from child and process for the same.

sample is as below,

**Html for Parent window**

```
<input type ="text" name="customername" id="customername" />
<input type ="text" name="customeraddress" id="customeraddress" />
<input type ="text" name="customertown" id="customertown"/>
<input type ="text" name="customercountry" id="customercountry"/>
```

open child window from here.

**Child page code is as below,**

```
function post_value(cname,caddress,ctown,ccount,cpincode,id)
    {
        window.opener.document.getElementById('customername').value = cname;
        window.opener.document.getElementById('customeraddress').value = caddress;
        window.opener.document.getElementById('customertown').value = ctown;
        window.opener.document.getElementById('customercountry').value = ccount;
        self.close();
        window.close();
        return false;
    }
```

In above code add checkbox and php code to select record which u need to add in parent window.
Now see the result you will have what you wanted.

Cheers.