# Get Value from child window to parent window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In Child window i have a table. When i click on it i need to get those values in parent window. I am using HTML and javascript. I need this in javascript or jquery.

Comment: can you share some code??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Please don't edit in bold highlighting on words just because they are the names of technologies

Comment: @AndrewBarber:actually i was the first line which was "in child window i a table"... :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847687/pass-more-that-one-database-record-from-child-window-to-parent-window-dynamicall/13488727#13488727

Answer (score 0):

I think this sample is usefull

```
$(purchaseWin.document).ready(function () {
  $(purchaseWin.document).contents().find('#tdProduct').html('2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `window.opener` property in javascript.

In child window, write an event handler to listen for clicks, which can then use the above property to communicate with its parent.

Comment: To communicate with the parent/opener, call a javascript function defined in the parent/opener, with the value you want to pass as an argument.

Comment: @Adder Even i am saying the same thing.